# Scraping Facebook page rating with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape the rating of a Facebook page using Nokogiri but I can't get it to give what I need.

Let me show you:

[image]

To parse the "4.3" value and then convert it into floating point I did:

```
fb_page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.facebook.com/pages/Singe-Vert/113716970402?fref=ts&rf=131302280307240"))
fb_page.css('span._3tgt._30zy._2l02').text.to_f
```

However this return an empty string `""`

Comment: Does that span appear in the actual source of the page, or has it been added dynamically by scripting? Check the “View source”. The image you have given looks like it’s from the inspector which shows the generated page after scripts have been run.

Comment: Just took a look at the page source code. The span is there, except it is commented out within another element called: `<code class="hidden_elem" id="u_0_15"></code>`. What does that mean?

Comment: It looks like the page is being constructed with javascript using those `hidden_elem` comments. Since Nokogiri only sees the “raw” page you can’y use it directly to get the info you want. Perhaps you could find the `comment()` node that contains the info and then parse its contents somehow.

Comment: Nice suggestion, i'll definitely check that out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use a screen capture to represent data or incoming HTML. That forces us to type in the text just to be able to help you. Instead, copy and paste the minimal HTML necessary to demonstrate the problem, so we can reuse your input.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me but as you can see I've been a member for over a year. Will take note of that though. Will change it to markdown

Answer (score 1):

Several things are going on that are keeping you from getting what you want.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="clearfix _15v7 _2103 _5vb9">
  <div class="_4bl7">
    <div class="_2fb5 _2fb4">
      <span class="_3tgt _30zy _2l02">
        "4.3 "
        <span class="_3tgv _30zz">*</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
EOT
```

First, you're using `css` to find a single element. Don't do that. `css`, like `search` returns a NodeSet, not a single node:

```
doc.css('._2l02').class # => Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet
doc.at('._2l02').class # => Nokogiri::XML::Element
```

The difference, and why you should be careful, is somewhat glossed over because you're using `text`, but you can run into very confusing results in more complex HTML unless you pay attention to the difference of the two.

To get at the value:

```
doc.at('._2l02').children.first.text # => "\n        \"4.3 \"\n        "
doc.at('._2l02').children.first.text[/[\d.]+/] # => "4.3"
doc.at('._2l02').children.first.text[/[\d.]+/].to_f # => 4.3
```

`doc.at('._2l02').children.first.text` gets the text from the first child node of the first HTML node with a class of `_2l02`.

`text[/[\d.]+/]` returns the digits and decimal.

Then it's clear sailing.

The reason you're getting an empty string is because the value you're getting starts with `"`:

```
str = "\"4.3 \"" # => "\"4.3 \""
str.to_f # => 0.0
```

To get around that I used a pattern to grab only digits and the decimal:

```
str[/[\d.]+/] # => "4.3"
str[/[\d.]+/].to_f # => 4.3
```

The same result could be achieved other ways too:

```
str.delete('"').to_f # => 4.3
str.gsub('"', '').to_f # => 4.3
str[1 .. -2].to_f # => 4.3
```

It's programmer choice which you use.